# Akamai Media Player: Get event callback when it's ready to play

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, media-player, akamai

I'm using the Akamai Media Player to stream video for an event. Normally the video stream starts the the "LIVE" position, but I would like mine to default to an earlier point in the video stream so that when users come to my page they always see something cool to start instead of the empty event grounds when the event isn't actively happening.

I'm trying to find a way to receive a callback when the video player is ready to go so I can tell it to seek back to the right number of seconds. The documentation says there is a 'loadeddata' callback, but for the life of me I can't get it to work. I'm never receiving any notifications. I can just set up a javascript timeout for 1.5 seconds that will cause it to seek back to the right time, but then I create a race condition and if the flash player (akamai player) hasn't properly loaded at that point it still won't work.

Documentation for the Media Player: http://videotest.esmas.com.mx/avp/userGuide/AkamaiPlayer_UserGuide.pdf

Any suggestions?